Multiple SaveChangesAsync calls in a TransactionScope creates a timeout
I have a simple situation where I'm using EF Core and TransactionScope (I cannot use, so don't recommend it, context.Database.UseTransaction or anything else from the DbContext, the first actions the transaction maintains aren't related to a DB so there is no DbContext) from System.Transactions, however (as we know) EF doesn't maintain any concept of order for inserts, so if you have
var a = new o1 { Id = "Id1" }
await ctx.AddAsync(a);

// some other code

var b = new o2 { Id = "Id2", aId = a.Id }
await ctx.AddAsync(b);

await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

There's a good chance you get a foreign key error as there's no guarantee a will save before b, so we're supposed to add await ctx.SaveChangesAsync() after calling ctx.AddAsync(a); like this.
var a = new o1 { Id = "Id1" }
await ctx.AddAsync(a);
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

// some other code

var b = new o2 { Id = "Id2", aId = a.Id }
await ctx.AddAsync(b);

await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

Here we have a problem though.
That works all well and fine when you don't have a TransactionScope. Once you wrap the above in a TransactionScope you end up with a Timeout being generated on the second call to await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
  var a = new o1 { Id = "Id1" }
  await ctx.AddAsync(a);
  await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

  // some other code

  var b = new o2 { Id = "Id2", aId = a.Id }
  await ctx.AddAsync(b);

  await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
  // Never reaches here because the above line times out
  tx.Commit();
}

I've not found a solution to this. Has anyone else?

Use Add instead of AddAsync. Or await the AddAsync calls. Also if you have setup correctly FK relationships, it is guaranteed that the principal entities will be inserted first, then the dependent entities with a correct FK obtained from the previous step, so you don't really need intermediate SaveChanges{Async}. I guess all the problems you are facing are because of not await-ed async calls.

Why AddAsync isn't awaited? This is MS recommended practice.

The above is not the real code, it's just pseudo code that missed that. The AddAsync is awaited, and replacing all the async methods with non async methods makes no difference. I'll edit the post.

Regardless of a transaction scope or not, applications should aim to only use a single SaveChanges call per operation. For create operations between related entities use navigation properties where EF will ensure that entities are saved in the correct order and FK properties are populated automatically.
Instead of:
var a = new o1 { Id = "Id1" }
await ctx.AddAsync(a);
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

// some other code

var b = new o2 { Id = "Id2", O1Id = a.Id }
await ctx.AddAsync(b);
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

Use:
var a = new o1 { Id = "Id1" }

// some other code

var b = new o2 { Id = "Id2", O1 = a }
ctx.Add(b);
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()

If there is a scenario that "a" can be saved and "b" is not created then in that scenario use ctx.Add(a) but if we create a "b" with a reference to an "a" we do not need to explicitly add "a", it will be inserted via its association to "b" and the FK will be set and available after the SaveChanges.
The entire save operation is already wrapped in a transaction, so a transaction scope is not needed to roll back a "save" of an "a" or "b" if one or the other persist fails. Neither would be saved.  Transactions are only explicitly needed when coordinating rollback scenarios between two completely separate operations. (I.e. across two different database contexts, or the database context and an external process that supports transactions)
Have a read up on aggregate roots in Entity Framework and how navigation properties are used for relationships. EF provides a lot of capability to work with data without the traditional concerns of explicitly saving rows in order and manually populating FKs.
Edit: Example with a related data structure and navigation properties. This demonstrates both association navigation properties (Locations) and parent (Project) + child (Job) relationships:
    [Test]
    public void TestInsertRelated()
    {
        int jobId;
        using (var context = new AltDbContext())
        {
            var location = context.Locations.First();
            var job = new Job { Name = "Test Job", Location = location };
            var project = new Project { Name = "Test Project" };
            project.Jobs.Add(job);

            context.Projects.Add(project);
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Job ID before SaveChanges: {job.JobId}");
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Project ID before SaveChanges: {job.ProjectId}");
            context.SaveChanges();
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Job ID inserted: {job.JobId}");
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Project ID inserted: {project.ProjectId}");
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Job's Project FK inserted: {job.ProjectId}");
            jobId = job.JobId;
        }

        // brand new DbContext, new connection to database.
        using (var context = new AltDbContext())
        {
            var job = context.Jobs.First(x => x.JobId == jobId);
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Job's Project FK Read from DB: {job.ProjectId}");
        }

    }

Here we create a Job entity that is a child of a Project. The job has a many-to-one association with an existing Location which I fetch the first record for example. I do not Add the Job to the DbContext.Jobs. In fact I didn't originally even have a DbContext.Jobs DbSet exposed, I added it simply so I can fetch the job directly after saving. I add the new Job to a new Project and add the Project to DbContext.Projects and call SaveChanges. EF doesn't just save the Project, it also saves the new Job, setting the job's ProjectId automatically and associating the Location ID as well.
The test output:
Job ID before SaveChanges: 0 
Project ID before SaveChanges: 0 
Job ID inserted: 7
Project ID inserted: 22 
Job's Project FK inserted: 22 
Job's Project FK Read from DB: 22

Prior to SaveChanges no FKs are set, after SaveChanges the new JobID and ProjectID are filled in. The test fetches the new job using a new DbContext instance so no tracking cache etc. and the FK is set.
When using navigation properties the order is guaranteed and the FKs are populated accordingly. Where you cannot guarantee order is when you try inserting disconnected records manually and expecting them to be inserted in a particular order such as setting IDs client-side.
Using navigation properties and a single SaveChanges will most likely solve your timeout issue. If I had to guess at the issue, the second SaveChanges call is blocking on the FK constraint because it would be operating under a ReadCommitted isolation even if the TxScope is ReadUncommitted and the "a" in question hasn't been committed yet.

I don't see your example calling ctx.Add(a); so that will fail. With regards to the comment about why transactions are needed, as I mentioned I have other operations that aren't DB related that are captured in the transaction scope. Also as mentioned, Several SO posts have said EF does not mange order, so saying only call SaveChangesAsync once isn't guaranteed to work - there are several posts here in So detailing EF has no logic to ensure order of executing db statements and do suggest calling SaveChangesAsync more than once.

With navigation properties set up rather than setting FKs manually you don't need ctx.Add(a) if you associate the new "a" with the new "b" that is added. It would only be needed if the insertion of "b" was conditional (I.e. could save an "a" without a "b") EF will ensure that the related entities are saved in the correct order. Where you cannot guarantee order is when batching separate individual inserts.

I've added an example demonstrating that FKs are resolved reliably through navigation properties, negating the need for multiple SaveChanges.
